# How to configure program.cs to chose appsettings.[EnvironmentName].json

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have a .net core 6.0 project, where I am deploying a background service.

I have

appsettings.test.json

appsettings.staging.json

appsettings.json

Each configured to connect to different persistence layer.

Also, each has a different instrumentation key for application insights.

I can get the EITHER, the test or staging environment to deploy, but then the other other application insights ceases to function.

(I tried to copy the launchSetting.json file on deployment. That was just never overwritten)

But how do I ensure that the enviroment variable I have defined in my azure service, gets picked up in my program.cs file?
And how do I debug which environment is actually chosen when the code has been deployed to azure and booted?

my program.cs file:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostServices, services) =>
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(hostServices.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostServices.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            
        var configuration = builder.Build();

        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        
        var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
        {
            // Disables adaptive sampling.
            EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,
            // Disables QuickPulse (Live Metrics stream).
            EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = true
        };
        
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(aiOptions);
        ..........
);
```

[image: Image of configuration value for environment]

I have also added a variable: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
with the value "test" on my test resource.

And the corresponding configuration has been added to staging, but with the value "staging" instead.

However it seems that my environment variable does not use these particular values? How do I accomplish this?

EDIT:

I have now altered the worker service project, to be contained with a "normal" web-application project, this, allows me to host the worker service in the web-application, and this solves my immediate issue of sometimes the worker service doesn't start.

However, the environment variable issue persists.
I still can only deploy whatever is in the "lauchsettings.json" file, the contents of this file is never overwritten by the azure configuration, and thus whatever environment is chosen in the source code, is what is deployed to all three nodes.

There must be a better way to debug errors of this kind, than "run a website that confirms the value of the environment selected", that is nuts, for something vital on a system like this?

If you search here on the azure web-api, you can see what the "console" logs locally on azure, and thus you can check your boot progress, provided you have added instrumentation messages. This allowed us to figure out why the service wasn't booting, and which environment variables were selected.
[image: Azure webapi]

Comment: You want application insights for worker process or .net core app ?

Comment: Technically, its a worker service? I think?

Comment: Yup, worker service.

Comment: My worker service is not wrapped in a web-application, and your initial advice is relevant, however, even with our initial advice, the issue persists.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, and the webapplication wrap around the worker service worked. 
I do not recommend taking a base worker service project and trying to deploy it to azure. That is not a fun trip.

you solution defacto became a solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Addition to @Guru Stron Answer.

> But how do I ensure that the enviroment variable I have defined in my azure service, gets picked up in my program.cs file?

Add the below code in `Program.cs` file.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var env = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;
IConfigurationBuilder myconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

We can display sample value and check which environment value is displayed.

***Check the below workaround to load values from `appsettings.json` based on the environment.***

- Here Iam setting Values in all the `appsettings` files.

***Example:***

```cs
 Test Env: "values": "From Test Environment"
 Devel Env: "values": "Value from Development Environment"
 Production Env: "values": "From Production Environment"
```

- As you are trying to access value from `test` environment, Iam setting the    `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as test in `Azure App Settings`.

In  `.cshtml` file,

```cs
@inject IConfiguration myconfig
<h2>@myconfig["Values"]</h2>
```

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

### Update :

In `Worker.cs` file,
Add the below lines of code.

```cs
        public IConfiguration _config;
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger,IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
        }
          protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //var env = config.GetValue<string>("Values");
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                _logger.LogInformation(_config.GetValue<string>("Values"));
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
```

You can check this in local as well by setting the Environmnet Variable.

[image]

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: The problem is, that it is a worker service, not a web app, so it does not use the Webapplication.Builder, but:
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostServices, services) =>
    {

Also there is no index html page to display the environment variable on, it's a worker service that simply executes in the background on a schedule.

Comment: Ok..will check and let you know.

Comment: this is still haunting me :)

Comment: @MortenBork - Please check the update section in the posted answer.

Comment: The problem isn't local. I can verify and run the code locally just fine, and it will correctly load either test or staging, depending on what value I define in my launchSettings.json file. 

However!
When I deploy to Azure (via bitbucket pipeline) I have three separate resources, that host the test version of the code, the staging version of the code, and the actual production version of the code (Same code, just different appsettings file). 

And these will only pick the value provided in the launchSettings file in the code, not the value provided in the configuration created in azure.

Comment: Verifying with the deployed App.

Comment: The issue is, I cannot. 
The configuration environment variable defined in Azure, isn't being used. 
so when I deploy to test on azure, staging doesn't work. (As it is being deployed as test)
And when I use the staging option in appsettings, test doesn't work, because the azure environment variable isn't picked up.

And If I don't provide a local environment variable, nothing is provided, and it attempts to deploy all 3 as production...

Because I cannot get the code to pickup the environment variable defined in azure....

Comment: The solution to the issue was two fold: one enable local logging on azure to validate that the service starts up. 

To validating that the service can actually boot (via this log) 

Also making sure any async services run, same method really. 

And then on the cloud provided logging you just print the selected environment variables. That worked.